# Using SVG with IDs for subcomponents

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

I am trying (in javascript) to access parts of a list of SVG components in a little test page, but I am not sure I can achieve what I want this way. The main question is:

Can I have sub-components having the same id in the two SVG top components?

In the code hereafter I want to change the color inside the first disk and the first rectangle. Here is what I tried, but it is not working.

Any tip would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name=viewport content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<title>SVG-ID-Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg id="theSVGOne" width="200" height="300" fill="#d55">
    <circle id="theCircle" cx="100" cy="75" r="50"
              stroke="firebrick" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
    <rect id="theRectangle" x="30" y="140" width="110" height="30" 
              stroke="black" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
<svg id="theSVGTwo" width="200" height="200">
    <circle id="theCircle" cx="100" cy="75" r="50"
              stroke="firebrick" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
    <rect id="theRectangle" x="30" y="140" width="110" height="30" 
              stroke="black" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
<div id="status"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  let svgOne = document.getElementById('theSVGOne')
  let svgTwo = document.getElementById('theSVGTwo')
  let statusPane = document.getElementById('status')
  statusPane.innerHTML = 'svgOne => '+svgOne.childElementCount.toString()
  let circOne = svgOne.firstChild
  let rctOne = svgOne.lastChild
  circOne.setAttribute(('fill', '#ec3'))
  rctOne.setAttribute(('fill', '#e3c'))
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: you cannot have duplicate id values in the same document unless you create them in the shadow dom.

Comment: OK. Thanks. This is somewhat what I feared. I still need to check about this shadow dom though.

Comment: Al lot of [danny's SVG answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520800/danny-365csi-engelman) are about shadow dom.

Comment: For the second svg element you can use the shapes like `<use href="#theCircle"/> <use href="#theRectangle"/>` However if your intention is to change the fill of each shape put theCircle and theRectangle in a <defs> without a fill attribute. Use them for both svg elements and give the <use> a fill attribute

Comment: @enxaneta. OK. This  <defs> thing sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class instead of id on the child elements (you can have as many duplicate class attributes as you want in the document) and then use `querySelector` on each svg to target specific children.

```js
let svgOne = document.getElementById('theSVGOne')
let svgTwo = document.getElementById('theSVGTwo')
let statusPane = document.getElementById('status')
statusPane.innerHTML = 'svgOne => '+svgOne.childElementCount.toString()
let circOne = svgOne.querySelector(".theCircle")
let rctOne = svgOne.querySelector(".theRectangle")
circOne.setAttribute('fill', '#ec3')
rctOne.setAttribute('fill', '#e3c')

let circTwo = svgTwo.querySelector(".theCircle")
let rctTwo = svgTwo.querySelector(".theRectangle")
circTwo.setAttribute('fill', 'blue')
rctTwo.setAttribute('fill', 'green')
```

```html
<svg id="theSVGOne" width="200" height="300" fill="#d55">
  <circle class="theCircle" cx="100" cy="75" r="50" stroke="firebrick" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
  <rect class="theRectangle" x="30" y="140" width="110" height="30"  stroke="black" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
<svg id="theSVGTwo" width="200" height="200">
  <circle class="theCircle" cx="100" cy="75" r="50" stroke="firebrick" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
  <rect class="theRectangle" x="30" y="140" width="110" height="30"  stroke="black" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
<div id="status"></div>
```

## Don't use IDs

While technically you can have duplicate ids in the DOM (and make it work), this is very bad practise. Id stands for identifier and should be unique to be able to "tell them apart". You can't do that with identical ids (which `theCircle` are we talking about?).

Problem is, html won't complain about duplicate ids (no errors are thrown).

To actually get feedback on right or wrong markup you can go to [w3's validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and check your html there.

Eg. `Error: Duplicate ID theCircle.`

Working (but wrong) example using id:

```js
let svgOne = document.getElementById('theSVGOne')
let svgTwo = document.getElementById('theSVGTwo')
let statusPane = document.getElementById('status')
statusPane.innerHTML = 'svgOne => '+svgOne.childElementCount.toString()
let circOne = svgOne.getElementById("theCircle")
let rctOne = svgOne.getElementById("theRectangle")
circOne.setAttribute('fill', '#ec3')
rctOne.setAttribute('fill', '#e3c')

let circTwo = svgTwo.getElementById("theCircle")
let rctTwo = svgTwo.getElementById("theRectangle")
circTwo.setAttribute('fill', 'pink')
rctTwo.setAttribute('fill', 'teal')
```

```html
<svg id="theSVGOne" width="200" height="300" fill="#d55">
  <circle id="theCircle" cx="100" cy="75" r="50" stroke="firebrick" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
  <rect id="theRectangle" x="30" y="140" width="110" height="30"  stroke="black" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
<svg id="theSVGTwo" width="200" height="200">
  <circle id="theCircle" cx="100" cy="75" r="50" stroke="firebrick" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
  <rect id="theRectangle" x="30" y="140" width="110" height="30"  stroke="black" fill="#ddd" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
<div id="status"></div>
```